# python TypeError: unbound method error

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror

I have never seen this error before:

`TypeError: unbound method halt_listener() must be called with test_imports instance as first argument (got Queue instance instead)`

I get it when I run this code:

```
class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      alive = {'import_1': True, 'import_2': True};

      def halt_listener(self, control_Queue, thread_Name, kill_command):
          while True:
              print ("Checking queue for kill")
              isAlive = control_queue.get()
              print ("isAlive", isAlive)
              if isAlive == kill_command:
                 print ("kill listener triggered")
                 self.alive[thread_Name] = False;
                 return

      def import_1(self, control_Queue, thread_Number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_Number
          t = Thread(target=test_imports.halt_listener, args=(control_Queue, 'import_1', 't1kill'))
          count = 0 
          t.run()
          global alive 
          run = test_imports.alive['import_1'];
          while run:
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_Number, count)
                count = count + 1
                print ("Test Import_1 ", run)
                run = self.alive['import_1'];
          print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_Number
```

I think it is with this line `def halt_listener(self, control_Queue, thread_Name, kill_command):` In particular `self` but I am not sure does anyone have any guidence
for how I should be handling this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create an instance of the class first:

```
def import_1(self, control_Queue, thread_Number):
    print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_Number
    myinstance = test_imports()
    t = Thread(target=myinstance.halt_listener, args=(control_Queue, 'import_1', 't1kill'))
```

Comment: Ok yeah that worked! Now quick question, why would that work and just doing test_imports.halt_listener in the thread call not? Just for future reference. THANKS A BUNCH!
TO anyone using my code be aware there are other errors that I have yet to correct.

Comment: @KyleSponable Because you have to create an instance before calling any functions. Observe: http://ideone.com/SwkvY3. Doing `test_imports.halt_listener` won't work because the `halt_listener` function isn't bound to any instance